# puppeteer break-word when generateing pdf from html

Tags: css, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I'm trying to create a pdf from html using headless chrome and puppeteer. Everything works fine CSS wise and the pdf looks good. The problem is now when i'm trying to do so that some divs doesn't break on new page. I thought that maybe this could be done the old fashion way using page-break-inside: avoid but with no success. I can't find anything on their github api page either. Is there anyone that have managed to do this?

```
async function createListenPdf(html) {
    try {
        var jobId = uuidv4();

        this.browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        var viewport = {
            width: 1165,
            height: 1200
        }
        page.setViewport(viewport);
        console.log("viewport");
        page.on("console", msg => {
            for (let i = 0; i < msg.args.length; ++i) {
                console.log(`${jobId} - From page. Arg ${i}: ${msg.args[i]}`);
            }
        });
        await page.goto(`data:text/html,${html}`, {
            waitUntil: 'networkidle0'
        });
        await page.emulateMedia('print');

        var buffer = await page.pdf({
            format: "A4",
            scale: 0.7,
            printBackground: true,
        });

        console.log(`${jobId} - Done. Will return the stream`);
        return buffer;
    }
    finally {
        if (this.browser) {
            console.log(`${jobId} - Closing browser`);
            this.browser.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Facing the same issue. One fix can be is to adjust the margin to make it perfectly fit to the page, however, expecting puppeteer to handle this one, without have to manually adjust the margin.